# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/local/bin/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 69

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm currently working on a project that involves using Selenium for web scraping/automation. I've encountered an issue with GeckoDriver where I'm getting a selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException with the message "Service /usr/local/bin/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 69". I've tried searching for information on this error code, but I haven't been able to find much. Can anyone shed some light on what this error means and how I might go about resolving it?

```py
def create_driver(self):
        if self.driver is None:
            firefox_options = Options()
            firefox_options.binary_location = '/usr/src/app/firefox/firefox'
            # firefox_options.binary_location = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'
            firefox_options.headless = True
            firefox_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
            firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
            firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
            firefox_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
            firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-software-rasterizer")
            firefox_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
            firefox_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
            firefox_options.add_argument(
                '--allow-running-insecure-content')
            firefox_options.set_preference("permissions.default.image", 2)
            firefox_options.add_argument(
                'blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
            geckodriver_path = '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'
        # if service is None:

            websocket_port = self.find_free_port()
            if websocket_port is None:
                os.system("sudo pkill firefox")
                os.system("sudo pkill geckodriver")
                return

            self.service = Service(geckodriver_path, port=websocket_port)
            self.service.start()
            port = self.service.port
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(
                service=self.service, options=firefox_options, executable_path=geckodriver_path, service_args=['--websocket-port', str(websocket_port)])
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
```

I got this error

```bash
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 113, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/local/bin/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 69
```

I want to fix it and let my web scraping/automation keep going.